# which graph analysis is dependent to the connected components of a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, cluster-analysis

I'm studying algorithms to find connected components of graph., but I still don't know why is important to find connected components. In which applications do we use connected components of a graph?

Edit:
I want to know which graph analysis is dependent to the connected components of a graph? means that if i find the connected components of a graph, i can do that graph analysis easier. For example if i find the connected components, Can i cluster the graph easier? if yes, which graph analysis i can do better?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory). Read each sub-topic under the 'See Also' section and look at applications in each.

Comment: Basically, it's a way to separate chunks of the universe you're dealing with that don't influence each other, giving you a way to look at the relevant parts instead of the whole thing.

Comment: What's the alternative?  Unconnected components?  Your question doesn't make sense to me.  Are you really asking why we care about graphs?

Comment: @duffymo: no, i want to know which analysis on graph depends on finding connected components. i have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons to study connected components.

- Many algorithms on graphs can be significantly sped up by splitting the graph into connected components and treating each one separately. For example, the graph coloring problem is to color the nodes in an undirected graph one of k different colors so no two nodes of the same color are connected by an edge. A brute-force solution takes time around k<sup>n</sup>. However, if the graph has many connected components in it, each CC can be processed independently of the rest, dramatically speeding up the algorithm by turning one problem of size k<sup>n</sup> into lots of smaller problems of size k<sup>n'</sup> for n' < n.
- Many properties related to connected components (for example, 2-edge-connectivity) are useful for describing the "robustness" of a network to failures. For example, a graph that's 2-edge-connected will stay connected if any edge is cut. Connected components form an important theoretical component underlying this area of study.
- Some problems on graphs can be modeled and solved by looking at connected components. For example, the constrained clustering problem is to cluster the nodes in a graph subject to certain "must-link" and "cannot-link" constraints that force nodes to be joined or kept separate from one another. To check if any solution exists at all, you can find the connected components of the graph relative to the must-link constraint and then check whether any cannot-link constraints go between related nodes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: it was usefull, Can you tell any other graph problem that connected components help it?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what the graph represents, but there can be endless applications, since this basically groups the vertices into independent groups. Some examples:

- If the graph represents links between webpages, finding connected components tells you which webpages can reach each other by clicking links.
- If the graph represents a probabilistic Markov model (a very common mathematical model), finding connected components tells you which states can be reached by other states.
- If the graph represents connections in facebook, finding connected components will find connected groups of people.
- If the graph represents potential spreading of an epidemic, finding connected components will find groups which cannot pass the disease to each other.

So you see this could be useful in many ways when you have very complicated big graphs that you would like to potentially separate to groups.

Comment: Good Answer! +1 for giving practical applications.